# Azure blob metadata in angular 6 typesrcipt

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, angular6, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload blob in azure blob storage with some metadata. I don't know how to set metadata and send with the blob. Right how I am doing this:

```
this.blobService.createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile(container, path, file, (error, result, response) => {
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation:

- [Microsoft Azure Storage SDK for Node.js and JavaScript for Browsers](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html)

You can add options while creating a blob:

```
var metadata = {
    category: 'blabla',
    type: 'test'
}

blobService.createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile(
      container
    , path
    , file,
    , options: {
        metadata: metadata
      }
    , (error, result, response) => {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are only two ways to set the blob metadata, using the **rest api in C#**, ex:

```
[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DoesServiceRequest]
public virtual void SetMetadata (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.AccessCondition accessCondition = null, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobRequestOptions options = null, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext operationContext = null);
```

More can be found **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.setmetadata?view=azure-dotnet)**

Or via URI:

**`https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob?comp=metadata`**

More can be found **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-metadata)**

Comment: Check my answer, you can do it using the javascript SDK, I've used it and it is working fine

Comment: @Thomas Thanks ! it's weird that it's not in the Azure Docs repos. I'll talk to the internal team to surface it within azure docs, I upvoted!